# ARM Debugging - Cortex M0 debugger gpio changing while halted in SysTick_Handler

Tags: arm, interrupts, debugging, cortex-m0

I've been trying to figure out this one for hours and I can't see what I'm missing. I currently am debugging my program on hardware and I have set a break-point inside of one of the functions called by SysTick_Handler(). Despite having the CPU halted, my LEDs, which are controlled by the CPU on the low side, are "blipping" about every second. I tried setting a break-point in the function that controls these and nothing happens which I would expect since my only core is halted.

**Shouldn't my device be stable when halted since the gpio registers are not being modified by my code? Does the timer interrupt continue to fire even though I'm at a breakpoint or something?**

HARDWARE DETAILS:

MICRO: XMC1302-T016X0032 AB

TYPE: ARM Cortex M0

Comment: I would suspect it is not really halted.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer because my memory is dim and I'm too lazy to check.  I *think* that there's an option with the Cortex processors to leave interrupts enabled while debugging.  This is so that if you're working on something in-system and Something Dreadful will happen if the real-time control ceases you can still debug other things.  I believe this is in the ARM document pertaining to the core, in the debugging section.  You set one bit, and the behavior changes.

Comment: @TimWescott I am recalling that timers might be allowed to run during break... but interrupts? That would be a mess..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know that specific ARM well enough to comment, but the hardware timers continue to run, and on ARM, you can preempt ISRs with others. don't know how the  debug breakpoint is implemented.

Comment: Is it possible you've left a WDT running?

Comment: Watchdog was definitely still running. Hard lesson learned. Thanks @james!

Answer (score 1):

**WATCHDOG TIMER NEEDED TO BE DISABLED BEFORE DEBUGGING**

I didn't realize the watchdog time was still running even when core was halted. Behavior makes perfect sense now! Thanks @james